# Console shortcut to toolbar in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, console

Is there a way to bring console icon to appear in toolbar. Each time I've to either press the shortcut Alt+Shift+Q,C or select it from the Window -> Show View. If it is present in the toolbar just like other icons( Save, Android SDK Manager,etc,....), it would be easier to access. Having the console window always open, takes up space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always minimize it, the console icon will stay there itself you just need to drag the tab group and put it where you want

[image]

You can also have a simple keyboard short-cut for opening the same

you can change it by going to `Window->Pregerances->General->Keys` you can set it to whatever you feel is easy, in my case it is <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>

PFB snapshot
[image]

Comment: If i close the console the tab group disappears from toolbar. Exactly how to get that tab group ?

Comment: well you can not have that option in tool bar as you want but you can always modify keyboard short cut in such case, please see my ans edited for doing the same